# Adobe Flash 11.3 low latency audio support for streaming through NetStream

Tags: flash, apache-flex, audio, adobe, netstream

In the Flash ver.11.3 release one of the changes is:

> Low latency audio support for streaming audio through NetStream — This
>   feature aims to reduce latency for high quality streaming audio
>   playback. It addresses a very special use case of cloud gaming, where
>   the game is rendered at a server and audio and video are streamed to
>   the client.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4476911

Can someone explain me what does that mean? Does it mean that any audio streamed via `NetStream` will be automatically improved in latency respect in this version of Flash player? Or some special settings must be applied on the `NetStream` so that the audio will be considered as "low latency"? May be this change is applied only to some certain audio formats streamed via NetStream?

Generally the question is: do I need to do any changes on my server, which broadcast live audio via `NetStream`, or in the audio player which is built with Flex, which listens to this audio, to take advantage of this new Flash release?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some details in the [release notes](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/enduser-release-notes-11_3.html), which mention a new boolean property, `useJitterBuffer`, that has been added to `NetStream`.

[This article](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3705) says you can set `bufferTime = 0` and `useJitterBuffer = true` to activate the new feature.

Finally, [this forum post](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4428681) says you also need to use `swf-version=16` in the compiler options.

So to answer your question: you need to make the changes above on the client. The only server side change seems to be to require Flash 11.3.

Comment: Can someone clear out for me a related issue - does the low latency feature (sound and netstream) available for mobile or only desKtop?  Thanks

Comment: I also needed to download this: http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/updaters/11/playerglobal11_5.swc